# Excel Macro Loop - removing duplicates per column

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macros and would like to create loop that identified a column range and hopefully a row range to remove duplicates. Currently I have taken the long way around that created an excel formula to create the macro script for the below.

Any help with the below would be much appreciated cause I am now at 60 columns and need to add another 40...

Thank you

```
Sheets("Result").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("B:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("C:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("D:D").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$1:$D$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("E:E").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$E$1:$E$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Columns("F:F").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$F$100000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove duplicates from each row independently? If so, you have plenty of solutions! Or do the combinations of these columns create your actual duplicates to be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you only care about duplicates per column.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    'Stop the screen from updating to reduce lag
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Main loop
    For i = 1 To 100
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Columns(i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next

    'Reset ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop!

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")
    For i = 1 To 100
        TargetSheet.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will perform a column-by-column duplicate removal:

```
Sub Kleanup()
    For i = 1 To Columns.Count
        Columns(i).Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next i
End Sub
```